# Are Team Foundation Server CAL licenses transferable?

Tags: tfs

My organization serves the application development needs a number of different companies. When we develop an application for a company, we typically have users from that company perform the testing.

If we were to use TFS Web Access for testing, are we able to transfer the CAL license from one company's tester to another once a project has been completed? I couldn't find anything about it in their licensing whitepaper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [TFS licensing whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350):

> if the contractor is using the client’s Team Foundation Server then
>   the client must supply a Team Foundation Server CAL for the
>   contractor’s use. This could be a CAL purchased separately or a CAL
>   that is included with the MSDN subscription that the client assigns to
>   the contractor temporarily.

So yes, it appears you can transfer CALS to different users as long as only one user is using the CAL (accessing the server) over any given period. (I think a "user" is not locked down to a specific individual)

However, this:

> Team Foundation Server CALs are only valid for accessing a Team
>   Foundation Server acquired by the same organization

...implies that your customers cannot use your CALs, so would have to purchase their own.

It may be possible (from my reading of the white paper) for you to get a Device CAL, assign it to a laptop, and lend the laptop to your customer. But it'd be best to ask Microsoft to confirm that.

However, if your customers are only using the web interface for test feedback (limited to basic work item operations such as reporting bugs, responding to feedback requests, and viewing reports) they will not require a CAL. Clearly Microsoft recognises that your customers will need to be able to interact with your server to report bugs and feedback.

But ultimately if you're not sure, **ask Microsoft** to give you a clear (and legally watertight) answer. You can read the licensing documents until you lose the will to live (or even more than 3.2 minutes if you must), or ask a thousand of us to post our interpretations, but you won't know for sure unless you get MS to provide the actual answer.

Comment: +1 for Ask Microsoft. When in doubt its always the best choice.